# Excel N x M array of text data from Sheet1 to a list /single column into Sheet3

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I have an Excel with data in range Sheet1!B1:Z2000 and it contains about 1500 ID'd in that range in random places.

ID in this case is text data (example of data "334_2_975"), length can vary (an other example "433_13_1390"), but no special charters beyond numbers and underscore.

I want make a list of the ID's in the array in a single column into Sheet3 that also keeps up with the changes in the original data every time the sheet is calculated. So no manual copy&paste of values needed every time data is updated. I managed to create formulas that can concatenate the data but it requires manual copy&paste to get rid of the extra "0" values in the array created by the solution. Also it is important to get the list of ID's in to an other Sheet and not on same Sheet as the data.

So any solutions? I would prefer a solution with just formulas but if you have one using VBA I'm also happy to hear that and try it out. Under this an explanation of my flawed solution and a link to sample excel.

---

My flawed solution:

Create Sheet2
Add "=Sheet1!A1:Z20000" to cell A1
//Adding all the ID's in the array form but with 0 in place on blanks

Create Sheet3
Copy all from Sheet1, Paste ONLY VALUES to Sheet3
From Sheet3 hit replace and replace all the "0" with "actual blanks"

This formula in cell AA1 in Sheet3
=SUM(COUNTIF(A1:Z2000,{"?*"}))
//To help the other formula in AB1

This formula in cell AB1 in Sheet3
=IF(ROWS($1:1)>$AA$1,"",INDIRECT(TEXT(SMALL(IF($A$1:$Z$2000<>"",10^5*ROW($A$1:$Z$2000)+COLUMN($A$1:$Z$2000)),ROWS($1:1)),"R0C00000"),0))

I Drag this formula to Row number"valua in cell AA1" or until I start to get blank values.
This way can even concatenate the values but I need to repeat the copy&paste and replace values operations every time a want the list to update.

---

Link to sample excel with my solution and example data:
https://hydrohexcom-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/heikki_ruohola_hydrohex_com/EZCjS757vttFhpEWwauj3o4Ba3TZlFf91fL0FKeaxj9FWw?e=jKn6l7

Answer (score 1):

Unwrap the 2D table into 1D with blanks, starting in A2 of sheet2:

```
 =INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$Z$20000,QUOTIENT(ROW()-2,COLUMN($Z$20000))+1,MOD(ROW()-2,COLUMN($Z$20000))+1)
```

Now make A1's value "IDs" and add a filter. Click the filter down arrow and remove all 0's.

If your data also contains 0's, you might have to "clone" sheet1 to sheet2 first, exchanging blanks with a unique character that can be filtered e.g. "%":

```
=IF(ISBLANK(sheet1!A1),"%",sheet1!A1)
```

Comment: Thank you, the solution works but it is still a bit inconvenient since the actual data set in the use case is even larger than than the example and dragging down the formula for tens of thousands of rows is not practical but is still works.

Do you think there would be a way to include a "filter" for 0 values in to the index formula? All the actual values are similar to the ones in the example so no numeric values at all. Only string formed by numbers and underscores.

Comment: A simple trick to overcome dragging to the last 10000'th row: Type the formula in A2. CTRL+C to copy. Now F5 and "Go To" cell A50000. Press shift+CTRL+home to select all the way to A1. Keep holding shift only and press down arrow twice to get to A3. Hit CTRL+V.

Comment: As for including the filter in the formula... it can be done using a spilled array formula in Office 365 (only). First generate a column array big enough to hodl every cell in the table using SEQUENCE which gives {1...50000}. In fact you would need two of these. In much the same way as the non-array solution, you will use QUOTIENT on the one array and MOD on the other, inside of INDEX to return a single column vector with every value filled in from the table. Wrap it all in a FILTER(...) function and you are good. The formula in A2 will spill automatically into A3...A10000 in Office 365.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using your solution on Sheet2 and then adding a Sheet3 with a simple filter formula that includes everything but "0" from Sheet2 to get a clean list of values. But your original way of using INDEX and the row numbers works great. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @HRuohola thanks glad it worked. Kindly checkmark the solution so that others may know it has been solved.